# searching a specific html section(div) on bing search

Tags: html, search, web-applications, search-engine, bing

I am trying to search for keyword on a specific section on simple html file with site:yyy.com

i know there is something that calls "inbody:" for bing searches that return results that contains specific keywords inside the body section.

In my case i want to be more specific in my search and not to search whole "body", but in a specific "div"

for example, for the following source page, i want a query that will search for keyword "apple" under div_id "fruit" only and return a bing result if it does appear which in this case it does. but if i was looking for "apple" under div_id "vegetable" i won't get any result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fruit">
    apple
</div>
<div id="vegetable">
cucumber
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Web Apps

Answer (score 0):

The inbody function allows to search text (not html tags used in the webpage) in the body part of all the webpages it has on it's database.